# pgadmin4 fail to run query file with COPY ..... FROM stdin

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, pgadmin

Having this sql file trying to run on pgAdmin4 :

```
 

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: genres; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.genres (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    genre character varying(255),
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);


--
-- Name: genres_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE public.genres ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.genres_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);


--
-- Name: movies; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.movies (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying(512),
    release_date date,
    runtime integer,
    mpaa_rating character varying(10),
    description text,
    image character varying(255),
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);


--
-- Name: movies_genres; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.movies_genres (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    movie_id integer,
    genre_id integer
);


--
-- Name: movies_genres_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE public.movies_genres ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.movies_genres_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);


--
-- Name: movies_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE public.movies ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.movies_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);


--
-- Name: users; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.users (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255),
    last_name character varying(255),
    email character varying(255),
    password character varying(255),
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);


--
-- Name: users_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE public.users ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.users_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);


--
-- Data for Name: genres; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

COPY public.genres (id, genre, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
1   Comedy  2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
2   Sci-Fi  2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
3   Horror  2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
4   Romance 2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
5   Action  2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
6   Thriller    2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
7   Drama   2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
8   Mystery 2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
9   Crime   2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
10  Animation   2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
11  Adventure   2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
12  Fantasy 2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
13  Superhero   2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
\.


--
-- Data for Name: movies; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

COPY public.movies (id, title, release_date, runtime, mpaa_rating, description, image, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
1   Highlander  1986-03-07  116 R   He fought his first battle on the Scottish Highlands in 1536. He will fight his greatest battle on the streets of New York City in 1986. His name is Connor MacLeod. He is immortal.    /8Z8dptJEypuLoOQro1WugD855YE.jpg    2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
2   Raiders of the Lost Ark 1981-06-12  115 PG-13   Archaeology professor Indiana Jones ventures to seize a biblical artefact known as the Ark of the Covenant. While doing so, he puts up a fight against Renee and a troop of Nazis.  /ceG9VzoRAVGwivFU403Wc3AHRys.jpg    2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
3   The Godfather   1972-03-24  175 18A The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty in postwar New York City transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant youngest son.   /3bhkrj58Vtu7enYsRolD1fZdja1.jpg    2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
\.


--
-- Data for Name: movies_genres; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

COPY public.movies_genres (id, movie_id, genre_id) FROM stdin;
1   1   5
2   1   12
3   2   5
4   2   11
5   3   9
6   3   7
\.


--
-- Data for Name: users; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

COPY public.users (id, first_name, last_name, email, password, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
1   Admin   User    admin@example.com   $2a$14$wVsaPvJnJJsomWArouWCtusem6S/.Gauq/GjOIEHpyh2DAMmso1wy    2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
\.


--
-- Name: genres_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.genres_id_seq', 13, true);


--
-- Name: movies_genres_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.movies_genres_id_seq', 6, true);


--
-- Name: movies_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.movies_id_seq', 3, true);


--
-- Name: users_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.users_id_seq', 1, true);


--
-- Name: genres genres_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.genres
    ADD CONSTRAINT genres_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: movies_genres movies_genres_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.movies_genres
    ADD CONSTRAINT movies_genres_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: movies movies_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.movies
    ADD CONSTRAINT movies_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: users users_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.users
    ADD CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: movies_genres movies_genres_genre_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.movies_genres
    ADD CONSTRAINT movies_genres_genre_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES public.genres(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;


--
-- Name: movies_genres movies_genres_movie_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.movies_genres
    ADD CONSTRAINT movies_genres_movie_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES public.movies(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

trying to run this :
Getting error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 139: 1 Comedy 2022-09-23 00:00:00 2022-09-23 00:00:00
          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 2962
```

Comment: That looks like a follow-on error.  The prior COPY failed for some reason, so now it is not in COPY mode and is interpreting the line as a statement. Look further back for the real error.

Comment: Make your life easier and use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). Then you can do `psql <connection parameters> -f the_file.sql` 2) pgAdmin4 does not handle `COPY`. For existing answer to your question see [COPY from stdin failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698611/postgresql-running-sql-and-get-error-copy-from-stdin-failed).

Comment: yeah this is what i did run it with the psql cli thanks!